# SQL query to check whether multiple entries exists

Tags: sql

I have a table `det` with the following columns:

```
Name  ID
--------
A     1
B     2
C     1
D     3
```

I need a query to check if multiple entry of name is there for single id. Here I am expecting a result like this:

```
Name  ID
--------
A     1
c     1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a simple select query with group by

```
SELECT ID, count(*) from det group by ID having count(*) >1
```

Comment: If duplicate names can exist, use `...having count(distinct name) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery where you select relevant ID's that have multiple names

```
SELECT Name, ID
FROM det
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM det
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1
);
```

Comment: Exact result I got.Thnaks alot

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `exists`:

```
select d.*
from det d
where exists (select 1 from det d2 where d2.id = d.id and d2.name <> d.name);
```